# Rails: undefined method `primary_key' for ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic relationship for my User model. I am using Devise.

When I try to edit the user's details, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `primary_key' for ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:Class
```

The data submitted through the form is:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Ap0JP2bs/w9J6iI9rZahiKR1K8UEIi7rp33a4OutMbo=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"some_email@yahoo.com",
 "rolable"=>{"first_name"=>"Christopher",
 "last_name"=>"Columbus",
 "city"=>"16"}},
 "commit"=>"Update"}
```

The controller method is:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
    else
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, error: "Something went wrong, couldn't update your profile!."
    end
  end
```

The models:

**1. User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rolable, :polymorphic => true

  # Devise business
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :remote_avatar_url, :avatar, :login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  # For authenticating with facebook
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :rolable
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  # For authenticating with both username or email
  attr_accessor :login

  # Upload avatar
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  # Makes username necessary
  validates :username, :presence => true
end
```

**2. Customer**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :rolable
  has_one :preferences, :class_name => "CustomerPreferences"
  belongs_to :city

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
end
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Where does this error point?

Comment: @Marek: if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

Comment: Can you provide the model details?

Comment: @ManojMonga: just did. Please tell me if there's anything else that you need. These are the two models that are involved in the error.

Comment: Full backtrace would also be good.

Comment: Do you have `rolable_type` and `rolable_id` in users table? Also, are you trying to use nested form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your request hash, you are passing the `rolable` attribute as:

```
"rolable"=>{"first_name"=>"Cristian",
           "last_name"=>"Gavrila",
           "city"=>"16"}
```

You can't do this unless you specify that the `User` model accepts nested attributes for `rolable`.  However, you have setup your `User` as belonging to a `Rolable` rather than the other way around.  Nested attributes aren't designed to handle this inverse relationship - you may want to reconsider what you are trying to accomplish here, and modify the relationship accordingly.

For instance, you may want to turn your hash inside out and pass the `rolable` attributes with the `user` attributes embedded within.  Or you may want to turn `rolable` into a has_one association.